# Best online resource to learn Python?

Tags: python

I am new to any scripting language. But, Still I worked on scripting a bit like tailoring other scripts to work for my purpose. For me, What is the best online resource to learn Python?

[Response Summary:]

Some Online Resources:

http://docs.python.org/tut/tut.html - Beginners

http://diveintopython3.ep.io/     - Intermediate

http://www.pythonchallenge.com/     - Expert Skills

http://docs.python.org/             - collection of all knowledge

Some more:

[A Byte of Python.](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python)

[Python 2.5 Quick Reference](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR25/PQR2.5.html)

[Python Side bar](http://www.edgewall.org/python-sidebar/)

[A Nice blog for beginners](http://www.learningpython.com/)

[Think Python: An Introduction to Software Design](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to learn python from scratch - you can start here: http://docs.python.org/tut/tut.html - good begginers guide

If you need to extend your knowledge - continue here http://diveintopython3.ep.io/ - good intermediate level book

If you need perfect skills - complete this http://www.pythonchallenge.com/ - outstanding and interesting challenge

And the perfect source of knowledge is http://docs.python.org/ - collection of all knowledge

Comment: Dive in to Python is not an intermediate level book.  It's a book for experienced programmers who are new to Python.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the Dive in to python. Its an amazing book.

Answer (score 7):

If you're a beginner, try my book [A Byte of Python](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python).

If you're already experienced in programming, try [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org).

Answer (score 3):

I think [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) is great.

It's not about learning Python (syntax) but presents you small and fun riddles. Solving the riddles is based on Python but you can use whatever fits (your calculator, bash scripts, Perl...). After you solved one, you get to see how others have solved it and can discuss the pros & cons of the different ways.

Very nice **to get a feel** for how things could be done (*smart*) in Python. This site works especially well if you know a bit about other scripting languages or the commandline, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tut/tut.html) at Python's homepage is a good place to start.  Also, there are some screencasts [here](http://showmedo.com).

Answer (score 1):

These are unvaluable online reference tools:

- [Python 2.5 Quick Reference](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR25/PQR2.5.html)
- [Python Side bar](http://www.edgewall.org/python-sidebar/)

Other online resources for beginners:

- A good python blog for beginners: http://www.learningpython.com/
- [Python Video at Google Code](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/index.html#_python_understanding)

Answer (score 1):

[Think Python: An Introduction to Software Design](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tut/tut.html) is actually pretty good.

There's also a [video series on showmedo](http://showmedo.com/videos/python) about python.

Between those two resources, you should have more than enough to learn the basics!

Comment: Show me do is actually a great concept..

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Building Skills in Python](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python.html), also.  It presumes some level of experience in programming.

If you're really new, try [Building Skills in Programming](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/nonprogrammer.html).  It includes a lot of background and fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

[Google's Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/)

> Welcome to Google's Python Class --
>   this is a free class for people with a
>   little bit of programming experience
>   who want to learn Python. The class
>   includes written materials, lecture
>   videos, and lots of code exercises to
>   practice Python coding. These
>   materials are used within Google to
>   introduce Python to people who have
>   just a little programming experience.
>   The first exercises work on basic
>   Python concepts like strings and
>   lists, building up to the later
>   exercises which are full programs
>   dealing with text files, processes,
>   and http connections. The class is
>   geared for people who have a little
>   bit of programming experience in some
>   language, enough to know what a
>   "variable" or "if statement" is.
>   Beyond that, you do not need to be an
>   expert programmer to use this
>   material.

Comment: I learned and gained confidence with Google's Python Class !!
I recommend this... !!

Answer (score 0):

There are some screencasts on http://showmedo.com

Answer (score 0):

I learned from the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tut/tut.html)!

Answer (score 0):

+1 for [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[The python manual](http://www.python.org/doc/current/tut/tut.html)

Its a bit long winded sometimes but it tells you all you need to know to get going.

Answer (score 0):

[PLEAC](http://pleac.sf.net) , has a Python Cookbook , which is very helpful .

Answer (score 0):

[Learn Python in 10 minutes](http://www.poromenos.org/tutorials/python)

Answer (score 0):

[The Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007973) is absolutely essestial if you want to know idiomatic python.

Answer (score 0):

I consider [ActiveState's Python community](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) to be a great resource. Also
[DZone Snippets](http://snippets.dzone.com/tag/python/) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I first ran across [Software Carpentry](http://swc.scipy.org/) looking at lists of python tutorials.. but its a lot more than a tutorial on python. turns out what I really learned was how to use subversion, and that none of my projects are better suited to python than to perl... yet.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [Hands-On Python](http://www.cs.luc.edu/~anh/python/hands- on/). It is used as a primary text for Computer Science 150 at Loyola University. It is concise intro to Python while emphasizing good programming style and design.

Answer (score 0):

[The Hazel Tree](http://thehazeltree.org)

Answer (score 0):

Python Cookbook is very useful.