# Resources for moving to Python

Tags: python

What are good online resources to learn Python, *quickly*, for some who can code decently in other languages?

edit: It'll help if you could explain why you think that resource is useful.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111857/what-did-you-use-to-teach-yourself-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577/best-online-resource-to-learn-python

Comment: why is this a community wiki question?

Comment: Perhaps because it's a sort of poll, asking for recommendations (in contrast to a technical question that can have a 'right' answer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Dive into python](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html)

I have gone over it in a weekend or so and it was enough to learn almost all the idioms of the language and get the feeling of what is "the Python way" :-)

Comment: Python 3 - http://diveintopython3.org/

Comment: above link's dead (410). Look at [Dive Into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.ep.io/)

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you already considered that, but [documentation at the official site](http://docs.python.org/3.0/) is very good. In particular, [Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.0/tutorial/index.html) lets you start quickly

Comment: I often refer to tutorial from time to time.

Answer (score 7):

[Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html)

Comment: Hadn't seen that before.  Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 3):

**How to Think Like a Computer Scientist**

Python Version

http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/html/

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to follow the standard tutorial (I find it very good) and, if you want to have a lot of fun while learning the language, definitely check out Python Challenge (http://www.pythonchallenge.com/).

Comment: The standard tutorial is here (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Search "Alex Martelli - Python For Programmers" on Google Video. Good introductory (but fast-paced) talk. Related videos are also worth watching.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to read and immediately buy Beazly's [Python Essential Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328623).

This book's introduction to the Python core language is the best I've seen, and it's written for experienced programmers looking to get up to speed on Python quickly, a.k.a. you.

Answer (score 0):

I bookmarked this [link](http://www.awaretek.com/tutorials.html) on my Delicous when I was starting out - it's a bunch of links to Python tutorials.
 I like [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) and the standard documentation as well. It assumes you know the basics of how to program and concentrates of showing how to use Python - it uses some nice realistic and useful code to explain.

Answer (score 0):

[Building Skills in Python][1]

The best book for programer to programer [1]: http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/python.html