# What are the helpful online resources there for Python beginners?

Tags: python, installation, pylons

**Specifically for the ff: topics:**

- Windows installation
- Using mod_wsgi/mod_python
- Python best practices
- Python security stuff
- Using Pylons

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you meant to say "mod_rails"?

Comment: Thank you for the correction. It should be mod_python.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learning+python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577/best-online-resource-to-learn-python

Comment: *Nope* – it should be `mod_wsgi`!!

Comment: Mike, mod_wsgi looks great! Thanks.

Comment: To be fair, `mod_python` does have its uses. But running Python web apps is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

[The official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) is a High quality, very well written introduction to Python.

[The Begginers guide](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) is a good source of all interesting materials of Python.

I loved the original [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) but it is fairly old(10 years?), and doesn't necessarily document all the changes in the recent years. However the author has written another master piece that is targeted at Python 3 users: [Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/).

Comment: *DIP* gets way more credit than it deserves. It contains a lot of inaccuracies and bad code compared to other beginner Python books like *How To Think Like a Computer Scientist*. *DIP* introduces things in odd orders (for example, comprehensions before loops), often uses wrong terms (calling many iterators lists that aren't, even when it's fairly important) or wrong definitions (for example claiming that an iterator is an object with an `__iter__` method), and makes silly, misleading claims (such as suggesting that an important/actual property of tuples is that they are faster than lists.)

Comment: Mike: I guess those errors are all corrected in DIP3. Mark acknowledges those errors, I think. But the presentation of introducing the code and walking along to explain is excellent and I think thats why it gets all the credit.

Comment: Not to mention, the awesome typefaces used, easy access, and what I call "Written with love" :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practices: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Pylons: http://pylonsbook.com/

And obviously, the Python docs: http://docs.python.org

Answer (score 0):

Many of the beginners who start learning python , do over learning.  I  have seen developers learning arrays for weeks , threading for next week and by doing so they loose stamina and interest in python eventually.

If you do project based learning , i mean like take small projects and modules and execute them you learn to the point , focused and faster.

I have created this tutorial which teaches Python using sample projects , you can give a try ==> [Python for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjJ7WzEL-es).