# From where to start Python

Tags: python

hi folks i am very new to python, i just intall it and configure it in netbeans but did't get from where to start and how to write my first program in python using netbean.

 Any one recommend me some help, forume or any other resource.
 Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated......

Comment: How about the official tutorial? http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Comment: Or any other tutorial. Seriously, what question is this? "I just got myself a cup and a coffee maker, what do I do next?"

Comment: thanks to all of you. Hope you people help me in future

Comment: @hunter: We'd are  helping you.  You must actually do some work yourself, also.  The tutorial is the work you must do.  That's the help we're offering.    Also, please don't use repeated punctuation marks.  One `!`, one `.` only, please.

Comment: @hunter: You are welcome, and we certainly will. Good luck with Python!

Comment: Also helps to know if you've got any programming skills already - in C, Ruby, PHP, FORTRAN, Basic - any other language really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best online resource to learn Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577/best-online-resource-to-learn-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Zed Shaw's ["Learning Python The Hard Way"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=learn+python+the+hard+way).  Or S. Lott's ["Building Python Skills"](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python.html).

UPDATE: I should have thought of the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) first.

If you'd be willing to consider books, I've gotten a great deal out of Wesley Chun's ["Core Python Programming".](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132269937)

Comment: I still feel the official Python tutorial is the best bet! S. Lott's book is good but 1). It has lots of errors. 2). S. Lott doesn't like PEP8 at all :-)

Comment: -1 For "Learning Python the hard way". It is confusing and misleading, IMO.

Comment: @Lennart: -1 seriously? The book is not bad. That is your perception.

Comment: @A A: There is a lot of questions here on SO of people being confused by LPTHW, an most of the time I have to agree with them, the book is confusing and misleading. That never seem to happen with other Python books. So yeah, seriously. Too bad that S. Lott's book doesn't like PEP8 and has errors. I also heard that Dive into Python has it's share of problems too. But I do *not* want to write another Python book right now. ;-P

Comment: @Lennart: I also think "Learning Python the hard way" is confusing and tedious, but I think downvoting means "this information is wrong" or "this does not belong here at all" and not "I have a different opinion on this topic".

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend avoiding use of an IDE like NetBeans until you know how to use Python a bit more without it.  I'd play around in the interactive terminal, accessible by typing `python` into a command prompt (or on windows, finding and running the `python.exe` file).  As far as resources, there are a million easily available on Google.  One you might want to use is "[Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index)"

Comment: If you are going to use an IDE, try IDLE: http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html