# Python programming

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best online resource to learn Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577/best-online-resource-to-learn-python)

i am a newbee in programming languages...and want to learn python(knows c,java),,,can anybody suggest me a good e-book or links to learn the basics of the same....

Comment: [The official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) is the best.

Comment: In addition to being a duplicate, this question suffers from very bad punctuation and grammar. Please, a little more effort.

Comment: is python a cross-platform language...i mean whether the same code can run on both UNIX and windows..

Comment: For the most part, yes.  Of course, if you use the Windows API, you code won't run on a UNIX machine.

Comment: You can use help and dir once you are started with python.

Answer (score 0):

[Python doc](http://docs.python.org) is the first place you go. Thereafter, follow the various links there to learn more

Answer (score 0):

The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) is your friend.