# Good programming guide for a middleschooler

Tags: python

I hope that this forum is the right place to ask this question!

I am a teacher at a combined middle/high school and one of the eighth graders is interested in teaching himself some programming.

I've recommended Python as an introductory language. I have struggled to find any programming guides, however, that are accessible (from a language and tone perspective) to an eighth grader.

Are there any guides that you can recommend?

Comment: Have you recommended [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How to Think Like a Computer Scientist - Learning with Python**

http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/

It is free and aimed at beginner programmers. In my opinion - the best choice for your students.

Comment: I was following this tutorial, but seems down at the moment :|

Answer (score 3):

I think Python is an excellent choice for students who are completely new to programming.

The [Livewires tutorials](http://www.livewires.org.uk/python/home) are written specifically for middle schoolers.

And C would be the *last* language I would start anyone on.

Answer (score 2):

Does he have any interest in games? There's [Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python](http://inventwithpython.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index) is (ironically) very accessible and beginner-friendly. 'Hard Way' in this case refers to huge amounts of typing, which is a great way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

For Beginners "Head First Python" http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920003434

Answer (score 1):

i started with C at university without any knowledge of programming or whatever, i am sure he is better than the times i was a freshman.

but the important point of programming is not the language for the beginning, it is the understanding of solving a problem

teach him writing an algorithm then suggest C/Python whatever he can find his own path after learning about algorithms

Comment: here is a guide for c programming http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/a/cbeginners.htm

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow itself is a good way to find specific resources. Here are two questions that should help you to find Python resources (most answers specify beginner/intermediate/expert). Hope it helps.

- [Best online resource to learn Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577/best-online-resource-to-learn-python)
- [What is a good python learning resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101908/what-is-a-good-python-learning-resource)

Also, a lot of answers seem to point here:

- Python Tutorials at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

*EDIT:* I've found some people recommend DIP/DIP3 but many don't, so I removed references to it. And as @What points out in his answer, [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) is a very good resource that targets beginners.

Comment: I heard from many experts that DIP3 is a terrible terrible document.