# python programming query

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming.

My question is where to write python programs in linux--

1. in terminal or
2. any writing pad like gedit etc

Should we write one program again and again for running or we should call the program and run it.

Answer (score 0):

After you install Python (it's installed by default on most Linux-es), you have two options:

1. Terminal. Just type `python <ENTER>` and you will be taken to the Python interpreter interactive prompt. For anything but the most basic stuff, however, you may want to intall [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) - an alternative interactive prompt that's much better than the default one.
2. In a file. Save your code into a .py file and run it with `python myfile.py`

But first and foremost, start by learning Python - the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) is a great place to start. Among other useful information, its [chapter 2](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html) discusses how to use the Python interpreter for beginners.

Stackoverflow also has a lot of great resources for learning Python. [This question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577/best-online-resource-to-learn-python) for example, and many others.

Comment: To the downvoter - please explain why the -1, I want to know what  I did wrong and improve for next time

Comment: Someone downvoted for me too. I wish I knew what is wrong with my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning, or you are evaluating expressions, you could run Python in terminal, or use IDLE.

But if you are writing large chunks of code, then you should consider using an IDE.
You could either use Geany, or use Eclipse with PyDev. I prefer Eclipse myself.

For running, you can run it using the command python program.py, or just add the line

```
#!/bin/python
```

to the beginning of your program, grant it execution permission using chmod, and run it with ./program.py command.