# I think I find a bug of python numpy.polyfit()

Tags: python, numpy

I think I find a bug of python numpy.polyfit(). I use numpy.polyfit with the two same data,one from txt and the other from typing.But the result is different.Why?Please help me.

**this is my code:**

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import re
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fl=open(r'C:\Users\yanzhiquan\Desktop\4-6.txt','r')
def stof(str):#把txt文件中的string变成数据
    if str:
        [e, t] = re.split(' ',str)
        e=int(e)
        t=float(re.sub('\n','',t))
        return e,t
def avi(fl):#生成x y
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for s in fl:
        [tx,ty]=stof(s)
        x.append(tx)
        y.append(ty)
    return x,y
x,y=avi(fl)
f=polynomial.polyfit(x,y,5)
f=numpy.poly1d(f)
print f
print x[0:10],type(x),type(x[1])
print y[0:10],type(y),type(y[1])
plt.plot(x,f(x),'g',x,y,'d')
plt.show()
```

result:

```
        5         4         3          2
-0.6467 x + 3.384 x - 2.032 x + 0.5557 x - 0.06226 x + 0.00241
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] <type 'list'> <type 'int'>
[1.2, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 4.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.1, 4.0, 4.1] <type 'list'> <type 'float'>
```

The content of txt file is just the data.
Like this:

```
1 1.2
2 1.5
3 1.9
4 2.1
5 4
6 4.4
7 4.9
8 5.1
9 4
10 4.1
```

**this is my test-code,the result of which should be right:**

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[1.2,1.5,1.9,2.1,4.0,4.4,4.9,5.1,4.0,4.1]
f=numpy.polyfit(x,y,5)
f=numpy.poly1d(f)
print f
t=[]
i=0
while True:
    t.append(i)
    i=i+0.01
    if i>10:
       break
print x,type(x),type(x[1])
print y,type(y),type(y[1])
plt.plot(t,f(t),'r',x,y,'d')
plt.show()
```

result:

```
         5           4          3         2
0.00241 x - 0.06226 x + 0.5557 x - 2.032 x + 3.384 x - 0.6467
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] <type 'list'> <type 'int'>
[1.2, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 4.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.1, 4.0, 4.1] <type 'list'> <type 'float'>
```

Comment: Why do you use `numpy.polynomia.polynomiall.polyfit` in one snippet and `numpy.polyfit` in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use two different polyfit routines.

[`numpy.polynomia.polynomial.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit):

> Polynomial coefficients ordered from low to high.

[`nupmy.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

> Polynomial coefficients, highest power first.

Thats why the order is of coefficients is revesed in the first example.
If the coefficients are passed to `numpy.poly1d`, `nupmy.polyfit` is the correct function to use. Otherwise the coefficients need to be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the coefficients obtained from polynomial.polyfit for numpy.poly1d you have to reverse the order.

This can be done by using:

```
f = polynomial.polyfit(x,y,5)
f = numpy.poly1d(f[::-1])  ## Here is the change
```

You should improve your coding style to be able to solve harder problems. You are using a variable f that completely changes it meaning during the course of the script. Why not use one variable fit_params and another fit_function? By doing so you could have easily found your bug by comparing fit_params.

And you should see the basic feature of python and numpy. Some code can be replaced very inefficiently by using standard numpy code. For example:

```
t=[]
i=0
while True:
    t.append(i)
    i=i+0.01
    if i>10:
       break
```

can just be:

```
t2 = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 10001)
```

You will be much better, when you take the time to learn from some basic tutorials, e.g. some good links can be found here:
[Best online resource to learn Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577/best-online-resource-to-learn-python)

Comment: "Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted."  [Michael Berkowski]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how kazemakase was a bit quicker to spot the problem and write an answer, I will just add that you can replace this line of code in your first example:

```
f = polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 5)
```

With this line:

```
f = polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 5)[::-1]
```

To obtain the same order of coefficients in both cases.